# Why does this calculation (division) return a wrong result?

Tags: c++

I'm having a strange problem with C++. In an OpenGL code I tried to compute a simple expression this way

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
    double posx = (x-300)/300;
    double posy = -1*(y-300)/300;

    switch(button){
        case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
            if(state == GLUT_DOWN){
                if(count < max){
                    particles[count].x = posx;
                    particles[count].y = posy;
                    particles[count].active = true;
                    count++;
                }

                glutPostRedisplay();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

but for some reason every particle appear on the center of screen. Strangely when I replace `double posx = (x-300)/300` with

```
double posx;
posx = x-300;
posx = posx/300;
```

(same for y) the code works... Anyone knows why it is happening? Maybe it is a very simple thing that i'm doing wrong. It's been ages since I used C++, so sorry if it was a simple mistake of mine.

Comment: `(x-300)/300;` does integer division, while you expected it to do floating point math?

Comment: posx be double don't work? I'm not storing a floating value on x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x` is an `int`, `300` is an `int`, too. So the calculation will be done using integer arithmetics, i.e. ignoring the remainder. That is why the division will return `0` when you expect something between `0.0` and `1.0`. **For the result of the calculation, it does not matter which type of variable you save the result to.**

In your second example, you assign `x-300` to `double posx`. So from this point on, you do floating point arithmetics leading to the expected result.

Another way to make it work would be replacing `300` by `300.0`.

Comment: Ok, now I understand why put ".0" on floating values '^^ thank you and sorry for the noob question