# Why is the volume always calculated by zero?

Tags: c++, function, dev-c++

I'm beginner in using functions, and I wrote this simple code. But I don't know why the volume is always calculated as zero.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 double area (double) ;
 double volume (double) ;
 int main () {
     double radious ;
     cout << "please enter the Radious \n" ;
     cin >> radious ;
     cout << "The area = " << area(radious) << "\n" ;
     cin >> radious ;
     cout << "The volume = " << volume(radious) << "\n" ;
     cout << radious << "\n" ;
 }

 // defintion function of the area 
 double area (double R) {
     return ( (4) * (3.14) * (R * R) ) ;
 }

 // defintion function of the volume 
 double volume (double R) {
     return ( (3/4) * (3.14) * (R * R * R) ) ;
 }
```

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: Include the code in the question, don't post pictures.  `3/4` is `0`, and `0` multiplied by anything is `0`.

Comment: `(3 / 4)` is zero because this is integer division.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this calculation (division) return a wrong result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827246/why-does-this-calculation-division-return-a-wrong-result)

Answer (score 0):

Your function `volume` will always return zero because 3 divided by 4 is 0 when interpreted as an integer. This is because casting any real value to integer will simply result in discarding decimal part. For example, `2.7` as `int` will be `2` not `3`, there is no rounding, in a mathematical sense.

You can fix this in 2 ways:

A) reorder your equation so division will be the last operation you do, e.g. `((3.14*R*R*R*3)/4)`. Note that this is often necessary, when you want your result to be `int`, which is not the case here.

B) explicitly say that either (or both) 3 or 4 have to be treated as a real number (`float`/`double`) by adding `.0`, e.g. `3.0/4` or `3/4.0` or `3.0/4.0`. This approach is better in your case since you expect `double` anyway.

For more information refer to [Numeric conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) and [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Comment: "This is because casting any real value to integer will simply result in discarding decimal part." is unclear as code does no casting.  Recommend re-wording.

Comment: One could also do `static_cast<double>(3)/4`, for example.

Comment: @NotAProgrammer  `3.0/4` would be much simpler, as stated in the answer

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think it's a matter of taste regardless, but as the OP is a beginner, it may help them to know that this way is also possible, for example when they work with variables and can't modify the literal.

Answer (score 0):

The part `3/4` in your code performs an integer division. Integers cannot have floating points so usually the last part of integer is truncated, which leaves `0` in your case.

You can replace `3/4` with `3.0/4.0`to make it work.

Good Luck!